# Get correct answer in the comment

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments

What should I do if posting a question and someone **answers** me in the comment and the answer was correct? This happened to me many times and the other answers did not help me.

- Should I close my question (the question can help others)?
- Should I ask the user to create an answer?
- Should I accept the closer answer of the other?

Or what should I do? Any idea, please.

Example:

[image: Comment answered my question]

Comment: When this happens, most of the time the question is a duplicate. The commentor just didn't find it, or was sure it was one and didn't search. And, in fact, in this case, it is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can, if you want, use an @ reply in the comments to ping the person and ask for them to promote their comment to an answer. Some people would consider this to be the nice thing to do, but opinions vary (see below). You would then wait a couple of days for them to post an answer. If and when that happens, you would upvote and accept their answer.

If they do not post an answer within a reasonable time frame, or you don't want to bother asking them to do so, then you should simply write up an answer of your own, borrowing from and expanding on the information provided in their comment.

Many times (at least for myself), this is what I *hoped* you would do when I left the comment. I had limited time or desire to write up a complete answer, so I just left you a hint in the right direction, hoping that you would take my hint and run with it, solving the problem for yourself and learning far more than you would have learned from just copying and pasting complete sample code. Armed with all of that newly-gained knowledge, you are in the best position to write an answer. You know that your solution works, because it solved your problem.

When you write such an answer, though, it is *definitely* expected that you give credit to the original commenter for the hint in the right direction as part of your answer. Something as simple as, *"Like RC said in his comment, the widget can be frobbed by…"* will suffice. If you like, you can link to the comment itself (clicking the time/date stamp will produce a link).

Comment: Agreed, but one additional note: if you end up writing your own answer that provides little more than a copy-paste of the comment, I think it would be fair to mark it Community Wiki. If you expand on the comment, then there's no need for that.

Comment: That's not really what "Community Wiki" is for though.

Comment: @Paulie_D Community Wiki is for when the "ownership" should be held by the community rather than the poster. The poster doesn't have and shouldn't have any moral claims over the post in the situation I described, and by *not* posting it as CW, there's even a greater risk the original commenter may be denied the opportunity to edit and improve the answer.

Comment: **"questions rarely, if ever, need community wiki."** https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/the-future-of-community-wiki/

Comment: @Paulie_D We are talking about answers, not about questions.